# pass in a type as parameter that implements an interface

Tags: c#

I would like to create a method that expects a type as parameter. This type has to implement an interface.

I know I could do something like this

```
    public void FooBar<T>(T item) where T : MyInterface
    {
        // do something with typeof(T)
    }
```

but I would like to have something like

```
    public void FooBar(Type desiredType) where desiredType : MyInterface
    {
        // do something with desiredType
    }
```

This is an invalid syntax but is there something I can use?

Comment: Why are you using generics in this method in the first place?

Comment: sorry, this is just an example

Comment: You can't enforce that at compile time. If you're taking a `Type` _instance_ as parameter you can check the condition at runtime using `_type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IMyInterface))`. I'd recomment providing a parameterless generic as typesafe alternative as well.

Comment: @Pretasoc would you mind providing an example? What do you mean with ` I'd recomment providing a parameterless generic as typesafe alternative as well` ?

Comment: @Question3r With that i meant the first snippet you provided, which would call `FooBar(typeof(T))`

Comment: Get rid of the item parameter. `void FooBar<T>() where T : MyInterface`

Comment: @MikeZboray That would only work, if `T` is known at compile time.

Comment: @Pretasoc Sure. It's not clear why OP "could" do the first one but "would like" the second one. My interpretation was that they knew the type at compile time but if not they they need to check the Type object's interfaces at runtime.

Comment: @MikeZboray when I get rid of the item parameter and I loop through an array `MyInterface[]` calling `FooBar<T>()` what do I have to pass in for `T` then? Currently I would do `FooBar(currentItem)` but now I don't know what `T` would be then

Comment: @Question3r Given this information and what you wrote in the question, "do something with typeof(T)", it's `FooBar<MyInterface>()` because that's the compile-time type of the argument. Are you not actually using `typeof(T)`?

Comment: I use `typeof(T)` but using `FooBar<MyInterface>()` would always result into `typeof(MyInterface)` instead of `typeof(theCurrentClassThatImplementsMyInterface)` that's why I asked :)

Comment: @Question3r Well your current usage would always uses MyInterface. You are only inferring the compile time type right now, not using the runtime type theCurrentClassThatImplementsMyInterface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply write

```
public void FooBar(MyInterface item)
{
    ...
}
```

This allows you to pass any type that implements the interface.

It's the best you can do dynamically. I even doubt that you need the generic version at all. If you have something like `public T FooBar(T item)`, then yes a generic version makes sense, but here, you can simply use the assignment compatibility of derived or implementing types.

---

If you need the runtime type of `item`, you can write.

```
Type type = item?.GetType();
if (type != null) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
if (item != null) {
    Type type = item.GetType();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do what you are trying to achieve. But you can use reflection to check it and throw exception. However this will be runtime check  rather then compiler time check.

```
if (typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(myType)
    throw new ArgumentException();
```

or

```
if (myType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IMyInterface)))
    throw new ArgumentException();
```